# Excluding nuget package with x64 dll from output directory?

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2019

I've just added the nuget package `Grpc.Core.Api` into one of my projects.

The build platform target for this project is marked as `x86`, however the build process is placing both `grpc_csharp_ext.x64.dll` and `grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll` into my output directory.

At ~10.2MB, this feels unnecessary. Is there any way to prevent the x64 variant from being included (other than manually adding a delete command in the Post-build event).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see these two `.dll` files: `grpc_csharp_ext.x64.dll` and `grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll` after installing `Grpc.Core` NuGet package, and if I only installing `Grpc.Core.Api` NuGet package, they won’t be generated.

By checking the detailed MSBuild output log, this two files are copied by default task `Copy`. The logic(or control) of judging whether to copy or skip copying should be stored in .targets file of `Grpc.Core` NuGet package folder.

I then find the `Grpc.Core.targets` file under `…\MyProject\packages\Grpc.Core.xxxxx\build\net45`. If you find and open it, you will see the related settings:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Grpc_SkipNativeLibsCopy)' != 'true'">
    <Content Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\runtimes\win-x86\native\grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <Link>grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll</Link>
      <Visible>false</Visible>
      <NuGetPackageId>Grpc.Core</NuGetPackageId>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\runtimes\win-x64\native\grpc_csharp_ext.x64.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <Link>grpc_csharp_ext.x64.dll</Link>
      <Visible>false</Visible>
      <NuGetPackageId>Grpc.Core</NuGetPackageId>
    </Content>
    ...
```

The `<condition="'$(Grpc_SkipNativeLibsCopy)'!='ture'">` and `<CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>` make `grpc_csharp_ext.x64.dll` be copied to the project output directory.

I don't think this can be overridden or be changed or be prevented by using MSBuild in `.csproj` files. As you mentioned, manually adding a delete command in the Post-build event should work, but it works after the file has been copied.

**What I think/suggest**

I may provide a silly or risky workaround. I don't recommend modifying the `Grpc.Core.targets` file, but if you change to `<CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>` for `grpc_csharp_ext.x64.dll`, this file will not be generated again if you only build for `x86`.

This maybe needs to be changed by author of this NuGet package, unless these actions(copy ..x64 files to output directory when building under x86) are necessary or for some reasons that we don't notice.

Again, I would agree on considering using Post-build event is better.